# How to keep the user logged in with launchWebAuthFlow?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, omniauth-google-oauth2

In my Chrome extension, I'm using `launchWebAuthFlow` to authenticate the user via their Google account:

```js
function launchGoogleAuthFlow(interactive) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const manifest = chrome.runtime.getManifest();
    const clientId = encodeURIComponent(manifest.oauth2.client_id);
    const scopes = encodeURIComponent(manifest.oauth2.scopes.join(' '));
    const redirectUri = encodeURIComponent('https://' + chrome.runtime.id + '.chromiumapp.org');

    const url = 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth' +
      '?client_id=' + clientId +
      '&response_type=id_token' +
      '&access_type=offline' +
      '&redirect_uri=' + redirectUri +
      '&scope=' + scopes

    chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow(
      {
        'url': url,
        'interactive': interactive
      },
      (redirectedTo) => {
        if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
          console.log(chrome.runtime.lastError.message);
          resolve(null)
        }
        else {
          console.log(redirectedTo);
          console.log(JSON.stringify(redirectedTo));
          let idToken = redirectedTo.substring(redirectedTo.indexOf('id_token=') + 9)
          idToken = idToken.substring(0, idToken.indexOf('&'))
          resolve(idToken)
        }
      }
    )
  })
}
```

After the initial sign-in, I can use `interactive: false` to sign in the user again automatically. **But after the browser was closed completely, they have to sign in interactively again.**
Do I have to implement the refresh token logic myself?

Comment: Sounds like an intentional restriction to improve security. Try switching to a custom implementation like webext-launch-web-auth-flow used by e.g. Stylus extension.

Answer (score 0):

That's what I did.

I stored the user's tokens in their browser (`browser.storage.local` or `chrome.storage.local`) upon a successful login.

Then, next time the LogIn button is clicked, it would check for the tokens (and their expiry) and open `chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow` conditionally